# How audio player in vkontakte.ru is done

Tags: flash, web-applications

In russian social network there is a functionality to play music online. Nothing special but music continues playing even if I'm navigating on the site. So Url is changing (not hash part) but music is playing smoothly.

How is it done? Just I'm curios how these guys did it so well.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So they are using history manipulation via javascript. This way they modify the url of the browser without reloading the page.
Examples can be seen [on mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 1):

Dutzi is correct. They are using AJAX calls to refresh all of the page other than the actual music/video player. If you look at Firebug in Firefox, when you click on a page the NET requests are not being refreshed they are being done added to the main queue. Try opening up a music player, firebug(net panel) and switching pages around. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The page doesn't reload, it's just ajax requests changing parts of the page, or an iframe.

For the URL bar, they're probably using something like [swfaddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/).

Comment: You mean that swfaddress allow changing the URL in the browser navigation bar without reloading page?